# Gitbook-style glossary in blogdown

Tags: blogdown

I am trying to add the glossary function of legacy gitbook to blogdown with Hugo. In gitbook, this feature automatically generated an `<a>` tag for terms listed in a separate glossary.md file. The glossary file is structured as:

```
## Term 1
Definition 1

## Term 2
Definition 2
```

A working example (in legacy gitbook) can be seen [here](http://www.partone.litfl.com/pituitary_and_hypothalamus.html).

I cannot find a way to do this in Hugo, but think I should be able to with blogdown. Could I use a `build.R` script to call a separate function to conduct a find & replace on the .rmd files, replacing each instance of a string `Term X` with a `<span title="Definition X">Term X</span>`?

The envisaged workflow would be something like:

1. Copy content directory, so original content dir remains unchanged
2. Find & replace terms (from terms in glossary document, to text in content directory)
3. Call blogdown to build HTML
4. Blogdown calls Hugo to render site

Is this a reasonable approach/is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out. My reading suggests that using `lapply` or others in the `apply` family are more computationally efficient in R but I cracked the nut with `for` loops earlier.

In the `build.R` script:

```
#Ensure working directory is the site root

library(R.utils)
library(xfun)

#Move everything to a safe space
copyDirectory(from="content", to="working", recursive=TRUE)

#Draws the glossary from a separate .md file, and separates it out into terms and definitions
glossary <- lapply(strsplit(readLines(con = "content/glossary.md", warn = FALSE), "## |##"), function(x){x[!x ==""]})
glossary <- glossary[lapply(glossary, length)>0] #Tidy up
terms <- glossary[seq_along(glossary) %% 2 > 0] #Separates the terms
defs <- glossary[seq_along(glossary) %% 2 == 0] #And the defs. terms[1] corresponds to defs[1].

#Get files for site
files <- list.files(path="working", pattern = "*.md|*.rmd|*.rmarkdown", recursive = TRUE)

#Replacing bit
setwd("working")
for (file in seq_along(files)) {
  for (term in seq_along(terms)) {
    gsub_file(files[file], sprintf("%s", terms[term]), sprintf("<span title=\"%s\" class=\"glossary\">%s</span>", defs[term], terms[term]), fixed = TRUE)
  }
}
setwd("..")

#Build the site from the new glossaried markdown
blogdown::build_dir('working')
```